# c++ shared flag segfault

Tags: c++, linker, share

by accidentally, I linked with --shared flag with a hello world c++ program and got an exe file. but output is segfault when I run it. Can someone tell me the reason behind it?

way to reproduce:

standard c++ hello world problem in eclipse c++.
check the shared flag box in setting--> shared library setting.

build output:

make all 
Building file: ../app.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"app.d" -MT"app.d" -o "app.o" "../app.cpp"
Finished building: ../app.cpp

Building target: app
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -shared -o "app"  ./app.o
Finished building target: app

execution output:
segmentation fault

Thanks

Comment: You have built a shared library, not an executable file. An attempt to execute a shared library normally leads to a segmentation fault. Don't use `-shared` unless you want to build a shared library.

Comment: can you tell me why execute a shared library can cause segFault? Thanks

Comment: @cppython A shared library does not need an entry point (function main) so the system would not know where to start executing in your code.  Also an executable links in the C runtime code which calls main() and calls exit() if main() returns.

Comment: Can you explain more detain about segfault when executing the shared library? now i know what cause this segfault but i still confuse how to cause this segfault? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From g++ manual: 
--shared
Produce a shared object which can then be linked with other objects to form an executable. Not all systems support this option. For predictable results, you must also specify the same set of options that were used to generate code (-fpic, -fPIC, or model suboptions) when you specify this option.[1]

When you put the --shared option, it means that you don't want an executable, but a shared object.

In your case, you create a shared library and not an executable. This is why you segfault when your launch it.

Comment: therefore, I must add -shared flag to build (.so or .dll) file. right?

Comment: The .so and .dll files are both shared libraries. The .so is used under unix, and .dll on windows.